Problem with the syntax when running a report in zendesk
I recently started working with ZenDesk and have a question for those familiar with generating reports. I need assistance with creating two reports:
A report that shows users who have provided an email address for feedback and have not had contact with technical support in the past year.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
I created a date filter to include tickets from the past year.
I attempted to create a metric with a standard calculation using the following formula:
sql
IF (DATE([Ticket created - Year]) = (DATE("today") - 1 year)) THEN [Requester email] ENDIF
However, I keep encountering a syntax error. I then tried this formula:
sql
IF [ticket created - Year] <= today() - 364 THEN [requester email] ENDIF
But I received this error:
“You can’t use [Ticket created - Year] as a number and TODAY() - 364 as text. Use only numbers or only text. If necessary, use the NUMBER function to transform text to numbers.”
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
